# Can't find variable when parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

When I tried this snippet of R code. I have problem in parallel

```
# include library
require(stats)
library(GMD)
library(parallel)
# include function
source('~/Workspaces/Projects/RProject/MovielensCluster/readData.R'); # contain readtext.convert() function
###
elbow.k <- function(mydata){
  ## determine a "good" k using elbow
  dist.obj <- dist(mydata);
  hclust.obj <- hclust(dist.obj);
  css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj);
  elbow.obj <- elbow.batch(css.obj);
  #   print(elbow.obj)
  k <- elbow.obj$k
  return(k)
}

# include file
filePath <- "dataset/u.user";
data.convert <- readtext.convert(filePath);
data.clustering <- data.convert[,c(-1,-4)];
# find k value
no_cores <- detectCores();
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores);
clusterExport(cl, list("data.clustering", "data.original", "elbow.k", "clustering.kmeans"));
start.time <- Sys.time();
k.clusters <- parSapply(cl, 1, function(x) elbow.k(data.clustering));
end.time <- Sys.time();
cat('Time to find k using Elbow method is',(end.time - start.time),'seconds with k value:', k.clusters);
```

I has an error notification:

```
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'data.original' not found
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: could not find function "elbow.k"
```

Can anyone help me to fix it ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem relate to "variable scope". On Mac/Linux you have the option of using **makeCluster(no_core, type="FORK")** that automatically contains all environment variables. On Windows you have to use the Parallel Socket Cluster (PSOCK) that starts out with only the base packages loaded. Thus, you always specifiy exactly what variables as well as library that you include for parallel function to work. **clusterExport()** and **clusterEvalQ()** are necessary so as to the function to see the needed variables and packages respectively. Note that any changes to the variable after **clusterExport** are ignored. Comeback to your problem. You must use as following:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(GMD));
```

and your full code:

```
# include library
require(stats)
library(GMD)
library(parallel)
# include function
source('~/Workspaces/Projects/RProject/MovielensCluster/readData.R'); # contain readtext.convert() function
###
elbow.k <- function(mydata){
  ## determine a "good" k using elbow
  dist.obj <- dist(mydata);
  hclust.obj <- hclust(dist.obj);
  css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj);
  elbow.obj <- elbow.batch(css.obj);
  #   print(elbow.obj)
  k <- elbow.obj$k
  return(k)
}

# include file
filePath <- "dataset/u.user";
data.convert <- readtext.convert(filePath);
data.clustering <- data.convert[,c(-1,-4)];
# find k value
no_cores <- detectCores();
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores);
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(GMD));
clusterExport(cl, list("data.clustering", "data.original", "elbow.k", "clustering.kmeans"));
start.time <- Sys.time();
k.clusters <- parSapply(cl, 1, function(x) elbow.k(data.clustering));
end.time <- Sys.time();
cat('Time to find k using Elbow method is',(end.time - start.time),'seconds with k value:', k.clusters);
```